# Inconsistency in "Unanswered" category, when moving between pages

Tags: support, bug, unanswered-questions

I've recently noticed a bug while selecting the option "Unanswered" in question's category (mobile device). Whenever I seelct it, the questions gets sorted on the basis of "Votes".

> **EDIT**: It's no big issue as **Martin** has said, but when I move to next/prev pages, the questions **aren't unanswered anymore**.

But, selecting other categories works fine!

> Android Oreo (Chrome), Android KitKat (Firefox). Jump directly to **Edit #2**.

---

<sup>**Edit:** (*no more useful* after edit #2)</sup>

[The instance I clicked unanswered option in select element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcmLw.png)

[The instance it reloaded with votes option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbHvw.png)

---

**EDIT #2:**

The instance I clicked unanswered option (*adjacent* to **All Questions** heading) in select element,

[image: clicked-instance]

The instance I clicked "pagination buttons" (*adjacent* to `15 per page` text) to reload next/prev pages,

[image: pagination-instance]

As you can see, it is showing some questions with green mark, which means **they've been answered**.

Comment: I can reproduce it on my PC, when clicking 'Mobile site' in the footer.

Comment: I can also see the same issue on mobile. Basically, you can't get to the second page of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3):

I am positive this is working as expected. I went through the first 15 entries in this list. I believe the secondary sort criterion is votes. Remember that in SE terms a question is only answered is it has an accepted answer or one that has a score greater one. This was not the case for the entries I checked.

On the other hand, when I switch to votes, I get a completely different list.